# How to show a product custom field (custom SKU) in WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Is there a way to display my custom SKU under each product on the WooCommerce order page?

The custom sku displays fine when I edit the product, but it does not display in the order page for the product. I need this information to show on the order so that Zapier can match it with the Visma Account Software ArticleID of the product.

This attempt is based on the solution [How to add a (second) custom sku field to WooCommerce products?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290387/how-to-add-a-second-custom-sku-field-to-woocommerce-products)

```
// Add Custom SKU Field

function my_add_custom_sku() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'ArticleID', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'Enter Visma ArticleID Here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'id' => 'articleid',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'Visma ArticleID is for integration with Zapier.', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'my_add_custom_sku' );

// Save
function my_save_custom_meta( $product ){
    if( isset($_POST['articleid']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( 'articleid', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['articleid'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'my_save_custom_meta', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` to save this product custom field as custom order Item data, when order is placed, as follows *(and display it everywhere on orders and emails)*:

```
// Save as custom order item meta data and display on orders and email notifications
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_articleid_on_orders_and_emails', 10, 4 );
function add_articleid_on_orders_and_emails( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $articleid = $values['data']->get_meta('articleid'); // Get product "articleid"

    // For product variations when the "articleid" is not defined
    if ( empty($articleid) && $values['variation_id'] > 0 ) {
        $product    = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] ); // Get the parent variable product
        $articleid = $product->get_meta( 'articleid' );  // Get parent product "articleid"
    }

    if ( ! empty($articleid) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'articleid', $articleid ); // add it as custom order item meta data
    }
}
```

And the following to change "articleid" displayed key slug with a readable label name "ArticleID" (on customer orders and email notifications):

```
// Replace the label (slug) by a readable label name on orders and emails
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    // Not on Admin
    if ( ! is_admin() && $display_key === 'articleid' ) {
        $display_key = __('ArticleID', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related to this thread:

- [Change order item displayed meta key label in WooCommerce admin order pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893733/change-order-item-displayed-meta-key-label-in-woocommerce-admin-order-pages)
- [Display a product custom field only in WooCommerce Admin single orders for Manual Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892831/display-a-product-custom-field-only-in-woocommerce-admin-single-orders-for-manua)
- [Change order item displayed meta key label in WooCommerce admin order pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893733/change-order-item-displayed-meta-key-label-in-woocommerce-admin-order-pages)

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at your solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569890/pass-custom-product-meta-data-to-the-order-in-woocommerce-3) and this is what I am trying to achieve. All I want is for my custom SKU (articleid) to appear as a hidden order item meta data, visible only in Admin Order edit pages on each item.

Comment: This works. Thank you. But it displays on the emails too. How do I amend it to only be visible on the Admin Order edit page?