# How to add following code data in url WordPress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to insert field data in URL Wordpress woocomrce product

I used following code to insert data

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290387/how-to-add-a-second-custom-sku-field-to-woocommerce-products
```

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  You should consider reading [ask] and [mre] and see if you can improve this question so that others may be able to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.